# Smartphone can't connect to Google's services unless resetting the WIFI connection

Tags: wi-fi

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Plus, which has a very strange behavior that I can't explain.

Everything works fine with 3G, 4G. But if I use my home's wifi connection, sometimes I can't access google search, youtube, play store. For example, I'm using the phone and need to do a quick google search, I open Chrome and input the keyword in the address bar, then hit Go. The browser will show that it's loading the Google search, but will never finish unless I turn off the WIFI and reconnect, then hit F5 on the browser. The same issue for YouTube, Playstore.

I notice that this is the problem of my phone, because my wife's Iphone does not have the same issue, and laptops also dont.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: In the wifi settings for your network, is *auto connect* enabled? //Also, next time it happens, switch off wifi, turn on aeroplane mode, wait for a few seconds and enable both. That helps on solving wifi issues though I can't recollect the logic behind this

Comment: @beeshyams where can I see the setting? It happens all the time, like 1 hour interval.

Comment: I am not familiar with Samsung settings but it should be under your network you are connected to //You can try the aeroplane mode trick

Comment: do you mean the airplane mode? As I mentioned in my post this only happens to Google's services, and I can fix it by simply turn on/off the wifi connection on my phone.